# How To Add Graphics To C++

Tags: c++, graphics

its been 6 months since i have started programming in c++. I know c++ like not complete but comparatively good enough so i wanted to ask now  how we can add graphics to simple c++ programs?
like colors, fonts and stuff.

Comment: You can't. Standard C++ have nothing to do something like that. Also, do you only want different colors in the terminal window, or do you want a full graphical user interface with windows and dialogs etc.?

Comment: Like previously I tried to make a billing system so now i wanted it to look a bit more professional sorta like more than a black box

Comment: You've now asked two questions that have been downvoting (one very heavily) and are at risk of losing your question asking privileges. Please read the "How To Ask" article in the help centre before asking another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build GUIs with c++ I reccomend QT(http://www.qt.io/). It's easy and fast to learn. If you want to build games, draw etc. i recommend GLFW. Hope I helped :)

Comment: how I am supposed to map my c++ code to this?

Comment: @AmmadKh you'll first have to learn a bit about how the framework works and build some practice apps independent of your primary project. After that you'll figure out how to stick it together, it shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: I recommend wxWidgets.  There are more GUI frameworks out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to add GUI elements to your app I recommend to use an external framework. It would otherwise take a massive amount of work to start from scratch :).

Since you didn't write which OS you're on, here is a list of platform-independent GUI libraries using c++:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries#C.2FC.2B.2B_packages

As Marko, I also strongly recommend to have a look at Qt :)